# Why is request content null when testing this HTTP-triggered Function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a simple function

```
    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyFunction([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        ...
    }
```

and when I test with passing a guid in quotes (I've tried without quotes as well)

[image]

the part where I deserialize the request content

```
await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

fails with

> JSON content found and type 'System.Guid' is not nullable. Path '',
>   line 0, position 0

Anyway to figure out why?

Comment: Where in the code are you using `Guid` type? Add that to your snippet. Btw, you shouldn't send request body in GET request, use POST instead.

Comment: You are passing content as "Body". Your function is "GET" and NOT "POST". Due to this, you are getting error.

Comment: ...or just send that GUID as a query parameter instead.